# "Seeing" what is in the asp.net data cache

Tags: asp.net, caching

Is there a way to see what is in the ASP.NET data cache at any given time? For example to render the contents as a hashtable view (key/object id)?

Comment: Via code or do you mean through the debugger?

Comment: I was hoping a 3rd party program that I could point to the web server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache implements IEnumerable; you should be able to loop through it using foreach... the enumerator implements this:

```
IDictionaryEnumerator GetEnumerator();
```

Answer (score 2):

http://aspalliance.com/cachemanager/

Answer (score 0):

Performance counters could be of help

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2009/07/20/monitor-your-asp-net-cache-api-behaviour.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4.aspx